# Javascript object bracket notation and requirejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, requirejs

I am working on a mini game project for the purpose of learning javascript, node etc. I am new to all of these and I am wondering how to create prototypes the right way especially with requireJS. The more I read about it and modules etc., the more confused I am ;-) For example

How can I write the below Object in bracket notation which I prefer, since it would save me a lot of "this" and makes it for me more readable ...

```
define([],function(){

  Ball = function(){

    this.x = null,
    this.y = null,
    this.vel = null

  };

  Ball.prototype.serve = function(){};
  Ball.prototype.update = function(){};
  Ball.prototype.render = function(){};

return Ball;
});
```

When I write it in bracket notation I get an error, Ball is not a function.

```
define([],function{

  var Ball = {
    x: null,
    y: null,
    vel: null
  };

  Ball.prototype.serve = function(){};
  Ball.prototype.update = function(){};
  Ball.prototype.render = function(){};

    return Ball;
});
```

And how do I inherit the correct way with requrejs.

Many thanks.

Comment: "Bracket notation" gives you a plain object, not a function.

Comment: I see, thanks. When do I want to define an Object as  function (can I say that?) and when as a plain object, or when and why is it necessary to differenciate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use an object as the prototype (instead of a constructor's prototype as in your first example), use `Object.create`.

An object does not have a `prototype` property that is used for establishing inheritance as does a function when it's called with `new`

```
var Ball = {
    x: null,
    y: null,
    vel: null,
    serve: function() {},
    update: function() {},
    render: function() {}
};
var ballInstance = Object.create(Ball);
```

A good way to visualize this is to understand that

```
function MyClass(y) {
   this.y = y;
}

MyClass.prototype.x = 'x';

var myClass = new MyClass('yVal')
```

Is the same thing as

```
var myClass = Object.create(MyClass.prototype);
MyClass.call(myClass, 'yVal');
```